# Tracking sport statistics with ggplot and geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this sample data:

```
df <- tibble(
  "Player" = c("Ryan Ellis", "Dustin Byfuglien", "Ryan Suter", "Drew Doughty",
               "Ryan Ellis", "Dustin Byfuglien", "Ryan Suter", "Drew Doughty",
               "Ryan Ellis", "Dustin Byfuglien", "Ryan Suter", "Drew Doughty"),
  "CF_Perc" = c("60", "65", "63", "70",
                "55", "60", "70", "72",
                "52", "57", "59", "61"),
  "Season" = c("2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
               "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017",
               "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018")
 )
```

I want to create a line graph where `Season` is on the x-axis and `CF_Perc` is on the y-axis. The graph itself will track the `Player`'s chosen statistic (here, `CF_Perc`) over the given years. This bit of code creates the correct set up, but nothing actually within the graph:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Season, CF_Perc)) +
  geom_line(aes(fill = Player)) +
  geom_segment()
```

Should I use `geom_point` instead, and then add in `geom_segment`? Thanks.

---

`CF_Perf` = a player's Corsi For %

Comment: `fill` is not a parameter for `geom_line`. You want `col`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `geom_segment()` ?

Comment: When I run this, I get a warning and an error that you should look at to explain why your plot is blank: a warning that `fill` is being ignored (check out `?geom_line` to see possible aesthetics), and an error that `geom_segment` is missing required aesthetics `xend` and `yend`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding grouping and color to Player seems to work for me?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Season, y = CF_Perc, color = Player, group = Player)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

You need to specify a group because your x and y are variables. You should probably reconsider this and convert it to numeric like I did.

```
df$CF_Perc <- as.numeric(as.character(df$CF_Perc))
df$Season <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Season))

ggplot(df, aes(x = Season, y = CF_Perc, color = Player)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Any idea when a grouping is needed along with specifying the color? I just add it in whenever `ggplot` complains but never know why.

Comment: @Chris because you are using factors instead of numeric values. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said above, this is a good example of why you should pay attention to your warnings and errors to help you do some simple debugging. Running your code, I get two lessons in the console:

```r
library(tidyverse)

...

ggplot(df, aes(Season, CF_Perc)) +
  geom_line(aes(fill = Player)) +
  geom_segment()
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
#> Error: geom_segment requires the following missing aesthetics: xend, yend
```

Looking at the docs shows that `geom_line` has an aesthetic `color`, not `fill`, as the warning points out. Likewise, `?geom_segment` shows that `xend` and `yend` are required.

I'm not sure what the goal is with the segments, so for now I'm dropping them and just taking care of the lines. First, fix the invalid aesthetic (`fill` --> `color`), and you'll get a warning:

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust
>   the group aesthetic?

That's a cue to look again at your data, and notice that you have two numeric columns encoded as characters.

```r
str(df)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   12 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Player : chr  "Ryan Ellis" "Dustin Byfuglien" "Ryan Suter" "Drew Doughty" ...
 $ CF_Perc: chr  "60" "65" "63" "70" ...
 $ Season : chr  "2016" "2016" "2016" "2016" ...
```

That's probably not what you want, as it makes it awkward to figure out how to plot something that's meant to connect continuous points, like a `geom_line`/`geom_path`.

So make those columns numeric, and you're set:

```r
df_numerics <- df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(CF_Perc, Season), as.numeric)

ggplot(df_numerics, aes(x = Season, y = CF_Perc)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Player)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2016:2018)
```

[image]

tl;dr: let R's warning and error messages help you out.